# Properties multi plot3d in Wolfram

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, mesh

I want to plot multi surfaces in Wolfram by different properties. For example, one with mesh and the other without. Which command I should use for not meshing the second surface?

```
Plot3D[{u*x, 0}, {u, 0.2, 2}, {x, 0.2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {u, x}, Mesh -> 30, PlotStyle -> {Blue, GrayLevel[0.98]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ClippingStyle -> None]
```

Comment: @Bill : Yes, but when I want to mesh just one surface between multi surfaces, Plot3D command does not accept . For example, it does not read command such as Mesh->{30,None} .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Show[Plot3D[x^2/5 + y^2/5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> 4],
     Plot3D[x/10 + y/5 +3, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> None], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image]